# How to use Typescript Q.when()

Tags: angularjs, typescript, q, definitelytyped

I have a function that returns `angular.IPromise<any>`

```
onActivate():IPromise<any>
{
     return Q.when(true);
}
```

but when it runs this it says

> Q is not defined

Although, when I look in `Q.d.ts` file, the module is declared and the function `when` is exported.

How to use Q service in typescript classes?

The entire class is this:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/q/q.d.ts" />
module app.common.modals
{

export class RenameModalCtrl extends app.common.controllers.ControllerBase
{
    public viewModel: RenameModalModel;
    private $modalInstance: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalServiceInstance;

    static $inject = ['common', '$translate', '$modalInstance', 'viewModel'];

    constructor(common: any, $translate: angular.translate.ITranslateService, $modalInstance: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalServiceInstance, viewModel: RenameModalModel)
    {
        super(common, $translate);
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
        this.$modalInstance = $modalInstance;
    }

    onActivate(): ng.IPromise<any>
    {
        return Q.when(true);
    }       
}

angular.module('app').controller('renameModalCtrl', RenameModalCtrl);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: are you including the Q.d.ts file in your class definition file?

Comment: if you mean this line then yes.
/// <reference path="../../typings/q/q.d.ts" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add $q as one of your injectables in $inject. Then add it to your constructor as type Q: ng.IQService

edit: Thought you meant the angular q. I think you just need to import the module:

```
import * as Q from 'q';
```

Comment: this is ok if I want to use Q that comes with angular.
But what about the one from : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/q/Q.d.ts
This one does not have when in Interface definition, It's when is exported as a function.